# Is there a LAG function in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I currently store data in QuestDB. I need to return the result of subtraction between subsequent field values. Does QuestDB have such a function out of the box in the SQL query syntax? This is what InfluxDB has got: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#difference

Comment: Related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77580593/how-can-i-use-lagoffset-window-function-on-questdb/77580594#77580594

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet supported, but there is a ticket to track addition of LAG/LEAD functions here: https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues/1268

Answer (score 0):

There has been support for Window functions for a few months already, and even if `LAG` is still not there, you can actually get this using the `FIRST_VALUE` window function.

If you want to try it out, you can run the following query at the [questdb demo site](https://demo.questdb.io)

```
SELECT
    timestamp, symbol,
    price,        
    first_value(price) OVER (
        PARTITION BY symbol
        ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    )
FROM
    trades
where timestamp in '2024' and symbol = 'BTC-USD'
```