# How can I use lag(offset) window function on QuestDB?

Tags: sql, database, time-series, window-functions, questdb

I know QuestDB has some window functions, but `lag` is still not supported. I have been using `LT JOINS` to get the value from the previous row. This is not ideal (query more verbose than needed and join performance) but it works.

However, I need now to get the value from the previous row and the one before. With `lag` I could use the offset argument, but without it I am at lost.

In other databases I can write this:

```
SELECT timestamp, 
price, 
Lag(price, 1) OVER(ORDER BY timestamp) AS price1, 
Lag(price, 2) OVER(ORDER BY timestamp) AS price2
FROM table
```

So every row would show the price, plus the price from rows 1 and 2 before.

Any ideas to get this on QuestDB? Thanks

Comment: This is an odd way to ask and answer your own question.

Comment: The question should show at least some data with desired output.

Comment: Thanks @isolated. I believe this is in agreement with StackOverflow policy https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=Type%20in%20your%20answer%2C%20then,better%20solution%20to%20your%20problem!.  There is actually a checkbox when you submit a new question to mark you want to answer your own question.

Comment: I can understand that, but the answer starts with `"You are right..."`, which is just kinda funny IMHO. Just made me slightly LOL.

Comment: Hey Luuk, thank you. I added more context. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @isolated. Note taken. Will change that as it sounds indeed weird. Thank you for helping me out here :)

Answer (score 2):

`lag` is not one of the currently implemented window functions on QuestDB, but you can use the window function `first_value`. By playing with the row offset, you can get the same result you would get with `lag`.

For example, if you go to the [questdb playground](https://demo.questdb.io/), you can execute

```
SELECT *, 
FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER (PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY timestamp rows BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS price_lag_1,
FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER (PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY timestamp rows BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 PRECEDING) AS price_lag_2
FROM 
trades 
WHERE timestamp IN '2023-11-30T10'
AND symbol = 'BTC-USD'
```

And you should get the prices for the 2 rows before and current price on each row.

[image]